# enciphered URLs laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

how to make the encryption shorter in characters?

```
\Crypt::encrypt($event->id))
```

Result:

```
http://myurl/id/eyJpdiI6Im5ub0hyaWJwVE1iendYbHNaSzJsSXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVHhpNmF4b3NlQjk2NFluRXhCOFZuQT09IiwibWFjIjoiZDkxNzk2OTlmZGRmZWJjYjFlNjExYjcyNWU4Y2Y4NWYwMjYxMTkxN2ZmNzU3NGM4Nzg0OWJkNjk1NmExNjVkZiIsInRhZyI6IiJ9
```

generates a very large link, I need to shorten it, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, I will show you some PHP functions I hope these will helps

```
<?php
$data= "Password";
$md5 = md5($data); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php
$sha1 = sha1($data); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php
$hash = hash('gost',$data); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php
$crypt = crypt($data); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php


echo "md5: " . $md5 . "<br>";
echo "sha1: " . $sha1 . "<br>";
echo "hash: " . $hash . "<br>";
echo "crypt: " . $crypt . "<br>";
echo hash_equals($crypt, crypt("Password", $crypt)); // For check if hashed data by "ctypt" equal to input
```

Output

```
// I think there are smaller as you want
md5: dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964
sha1: 8be3c943b1609fffbfc51aad666d0a04adf83c9d
hash: 243674170a09e1e5fc9aafae4ba426841efc9ad55a5c013d1277f204e3ecfa04
crypt: $1$3yXFeq2Y$YCALetipqV22Cc1sH9YYk.
1
```

---

You should add some salt to make your data stronger

ex

```
$data = "Password";
$salt = "g5s46df1s65df1s65d";
$sha1 = sha1($data.$salt);
echo "sha1: " . $sha1 . "<br>";
```

Hard to get clear data because an attacker needs to know the salt